# Only allow COUNT to Postgres role?

Tags: postgresql, roles

I need to create a Postgres user for others to query my database, but can't have them see the values of columns since it's sensitive data, they should only be able to see the counts. They need to be able to do count where however with many different possible permutations of the where clause. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do these `WHERE` clauses need to reference the sensitive columns?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, otherwise I know I could only give access to the nonsensitive columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing flexible enough to handle this case would be a [`SECURITY DEFINER` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html). Basically, the queries in these functions behave as if they were run by the function's owner, as opposed to the function's caller, allowing the caller to do things which they wouldn't ordinarily have permission for (in a controlled manner).

Of course, you need to be careful about what you run in there, and you need to be *exceptionally* paranoid when incorporating any user input into your queries, which is going to make things difficult if you want callers to specify their own `WHERE` clause. User-defined functions are probably out of the question, as a constraint like `WHERE my_func(private_col)` could simply write its input to a table somewhere. But something as innocuous as `WHERE private_col = 1` could be just as bad, if the caller manages to sneak in their own definition of the `=` operator; be sure to [lock down your search path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY) when writing functions like this.

All that aside, even if you had a perfect solution, this setup is probably not as secure as seems. You may not be exposing the values directly, but you're still exposing *information* about the values, and over the course of several queries, that's enough to reconstruct the values themselves. For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM private_data WHERE creditcard >= '00000000' AND creditcard < '50000000';
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM private_data WHERE creditcard >= '25000000' AND creditcard < '50000000';
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM private_data WHERE creditcard >= '25000000' AND creditcard < '37500000';
...
```

This is only going to take 54 steps to converge on a single number. Even a 100-character string would generally only take a few hundred queries to pin down.